# Should my apps UI/UX be as expressive and energizing as our content, or more calming to contrast?

Tags: design, branding, emotion

My app is about food videos. I find food videos to be very stirring and exciting. After looking at a gorgeous meal, I tend to need a moment to regain my cool.

Should my UI/UX be as expressive and emotional as the content, or should it be more of a zen and calming vibe to contrast?

The brand I’ve created is very fun, young, and energizing. Would creating exhilarating UX to mirror that pathos be too overwhelming? Would creating a chill/meditative UX to contrast that be off-brand and non-sensical? Thanks :)

Comment: This can't really be answered for you. It depends on the target audience and your own goals.

Comment: Hi, you might want to try this question in https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ as it seems more focused on branding.

Answer (score 1):

I'll echo jazZRo and state that it can't really be answered for you.

A simple way to test which would sit better with your target audience would be to design out both concepts–one zen and one exciting–and test those with people who fit your demographic.

The test should be focused on the feel and *perceived* fit of the design to the content. This is largely subjective from person to person, but the data may not be so subjective as to which your audience ultimately prefers.

Hope this helps.